# OpenGL SuperBible 6th edition, header file sb6.h missing

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4

Recently I started to learn OpenGL and; in turn, began to read the OpenGL SuperBible 6th edition, which uses OpenGL 4.3.

My problem is in the sb6.h header file, because in the book it was written that this is a c++ header file that defines a namespace called sb6 that includes the declaration of an application class.

When I try to compile my program, my C++ IDE(Visual Studio 2010) throws an error stating that such a header file cannot be found.

So maybe one of you heard about this problem or also started to read this book and knows how to fix this problem; if so please reply.

```
#include "sb6.h"

//derive my_application from sb6:application

class my_application : public sb6.application
{
public : 

   //Rendering function
   void render(double currentTime){

   //Simply clear the window red
   static const GLfloat red[] = {1.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f};

  glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0 , red) ; 
}
```

Comment: The first question then becomes: do you have that file? If you look at the Github for the book's sources, it's there: https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code

Comment: @Bart , no i dont have it . I will downloadd it from your link

Comment: Even though I started learning OpenGL (1.2) from the super bible, but it seems now to me that it's better as a reference rather than a tutorial. Take a look at [this book](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) also, perhaps you would find it easier to learn.

Comment: Im familiar with OpenGL , but this header file was messing up with me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the sb6.h file you are looking for is located at:
https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code/blob/master/include/sb6.h
You can also navigate about that project and see the rest of the source/retrieve any other files you need.  When you copy them to a local drive/directory make sure to add the path of the new directory containing headers to your include path and any libs to the lib path etc, as otherwise you will still meet the same error.

Well, unless you add them straight to the project dir (not recommended, as you will end up with massive repetition of content over all your gl projects, better to place them in one location and add the paths) Let me know if you need a hand with defining the paths.

**Additional:**

To include the headers, libs etc. just do the following:

Download all the sb6 project, then save somewhere (for example `c:\sb6\` )
Then, go to `Property Pages -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories`
and add the `c:\sb6\include\` path here
[image: header files]
then you will want to add the libraries via:
`Property Pages -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories` to here:
[image: lib files]
and finally add your source code directory via:
`Property Pages -> VC++ Directories -> Source Directories`
 here:
[image: source files]

**To fix error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup**

This is normally a linker problem and most often happens from the wrong project type being selected (ie picking a windows program project and not a windows console one).  It can be fixed by doing the following:

Go to `Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System` and on the entry for `Subsystem` change it to `Console`

Shown here:
[image: Change subsystem to console]

Let me know how you get on and I can expand if needed.

Comment: Yes i need some help with linking the headerfiles with the project

Comment: Hi Nicholas, was just editing the post and screen-grabbing updated now:)

Comment: Okey , now i get this error

error C2504: 'sb6' : base class undefined

Comment: The previous error with sb6 base class undefined i fixed it  .

Now its telling me that 

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

I know this is a issue that i dont have my main function 

but as far as i understand 

DECLARE_MAIN(my_application) ;

Comment: DECLARE_MAIN(my_application) ;

Stands for function main .So i dont know why this error is showing up

Comment: Hi,  I believe this error happens when you have the wrong project type selected: for example if you made a windows program and are coding for a console application or vice versa.  I have added a section on how to fix this error to the answer:)

Comment: Yes, i tried it before and did not worked .My project is also an console project. Also i tryed to make it windows application and it doesnt work neither.

Comment: could you post more detail on the error please and I can try and recreate it?  Also, strange as it sounds try a clean and rebuild, you wouldnt believe how often that can help.

Comment: Ok , lets start it from beginning .

I have a header file with the code included from above .

I made the link with sb6 folder as you said . Perfect.

My project is a console project , and in properties on advanced option i also have the selected option Console .

I dont know how to do a clean (maybe that is debuging) , but when i build it the error is :

1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup


1>C:\Users\Nico\Desktop\Test1\Debug\Test1.exe : fatal error LNK1120:

 1 unresolved externals

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40623/discussion-between-gmasucci-and-nicholas)

Comment: I will need to look at this tonight but will be available later on (post 6pm gmt) and can feed back more information.